# What is the fastest way to send post request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for my project I need to send post request (1 request) as fast as possible. Maybe there is something faster than requests module ?

```
import requests

r = requests.post('www.example.com',headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": xcrsftoken}
print(r.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

Comment: It depends on the speed of network mostly.

Comment: I have 0.1 ms to server , Its on code side now.

Comment: It's faster if you use low level code in written in Assembler and compile that with optimization on your machine. But I am quite sure you are fine with Python and requests :)